# Is datatable empty

Tags: c#, .net

I had a a function like this

```
con.Open();
int k = 1;
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select MAX (CUT_ID) from CUTORDER_MASTER ", con);
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(rdr);
if (dt != null)
{
    if (int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) != 0)
    {
        k = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) + 1;
    }

}
```

My issue is if there is no value retrieved by query the data table is returning a cell max(cutid) without any value. therefore it skips the null check and if O check and code reaches  `k = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) + 1;`
causing Exception 
incorrect  format

Is there any way to solve this issue and check whether the data table is empty

Comment: Calling `Load` on your `DataTable` will not let your reference disappear, so the `if (dt != null)`-check is pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
'select NVL(MAX(CUT_ID), 0) from CUTORDER_MASTER'
```

This query will return `0` if there's no data in table. I'm not quite good at Oracle but after a quick research, I think this will work

Comment: its oracle 8i database

Comment: @sreenathsreenath Answer edited, please take a look at it and tell me if it works or not

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `ExecuteReader()`, use `ExecuteScalar()` method and store the result in the variable. Then do null check with this variable. You are checking datatable instance.actually you dont need to use datatable in this scenario.

If you want to check with datatable, use `datatable.rows.count() method` to check how many rows are populated in the datatable.

Answer (score 2):

First of all my question is: why you are using datatable to retrieve single value. If you are not familiar **ExecuteScalar** Then read about this it will help you in future also. 
ok now come to the scenario you have used:

There are number of ways to do that:

If you want your result will contain **0** instead of empty value:

1) you can get it from database as below:

```
select IsNull(MAX(CUT_ID), 0) from CUTORDER_MASTER
```

2) using code:

```
if (dt != null)
{
    if (int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) != null && 
        int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) != "")
    {
        k = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) + 1;
    }
}
```

3) using code :

```
if (dt != null)
{
    if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) != null && 
            int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) != "")
        {
            k = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

and many more.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from CUTORDER_MASTER
```

this will also return 0 if no data in table ;)

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select MAX (CUT_ID) from CUTORDER_MASTER ", con);
object result = = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
int k = (result == null || result == DBNull.Value) ? 0: (int)result;
```

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query